# Is there a decent way for not definiting MapperFactoryBean for each DAO interface in mybatis-spring?

Tags: spring, mybatis

As we all know, we define a `MapperFactoryBean` for a `DAO` interface to interact with the `mapper.xml`. But with the increase of `mapper.xml` as well as `DAO` interface, I need to define more and more `MapperFactoryBean` in `mybatis-config.xml`. Is there a way which can automatically do that thing for me? just like the simplicity of `context:component-scan`， code one sentence, and spring will auto detect the bean itself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Have a look at the doc at:

http://mybatis.github.io/spring/mappers.html#scan